# Var in append not working jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I need help in this code, when I declare the variables the code does not work, if it does not declare it works

Here is the difference in the code below it performs normally

```
var i = 2;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
        count=$('table tr').length;

    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum'>test</span></td></tr>";
    $('table').append(data);

    i++;
});
```

When I declare the "+ count +" and "+ i +" it does not execute

```
var i = 2;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
        count=$('table tr').length;

    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum"+i+"'>"+count+".</span></td></tr>";
    $('table').append(data);

    i++;
});
```

Comment: The two code excerpts look identical to me... Did I miss something?

Comment: the second include declaration "+i+" , "+count+"

Comment: Please edit your post to show what you mean.

Comment: post edited again

Comment: Oh, I see. You changed ``<span id='snum'>test</span>`` to ``<span id='snum"+i+"'>"+count+".</span>``. I was confused when you used the word ``declare`` which was a specific meaning in programming. Also this text that has changed is far to the right. If the code doesn't execute, you should get an error message?

Comment: It simply does not execute, it does not add any row, and in the console it does not present any errors

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5qr7qk4e/ Works fine here. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the frst code that doesn't work becase you didn't use concatenation symbol '+' around variable test.

Comment: I can't see the diffrence. maybe you should explain what is means didn't work. Maybe some error message, or what you expect that didn't happen.

Comment: I tested your code, work both. There must be something else that you've missed.